# Finding java class from jar file in QT using JNI

Tags: java, c++, qt, java-native-interface

I have created a simple java class and exported as jar file.

Then I tried to load the java class in C++ using JNI but i couldn't.

But if I load it directly from java file its wokring but from jar file it's not wokring.

Pdf.java

```
package PdfCore;

public class Pdf {

    public int x,y;
    public Pdf(int _x, int _y){
        x = _x;
        y = _y;
    }
    public int sum(){
        return x+y;
    }

}
```

Test.pro

```
TEMPLATE = app

QT += qml quick
CONFIG += c++11

SOURCES += main.cpp

RESOURCES += qml.qrc

# Additional import path used to resolve QML modules in Qt Creator's code model
QML_IMPORT_PATH =

# Default rules for deployment.
include(deployment.pri)

DISTFILES += \
    android/AndroidManifest.xml \
    android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar \
    android/gradlew \
    android/res/values/libs.xml \
    android/build.gradle \
    android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties \
    android/gradlew.bat \
    android/src/XPdf.jar

ANDROID_PACKAGE_SOURCE_DIR = $$PWD/android
```

main.cpp

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <QDebug>

static JavaVM* s_javaVM = 0;
static jclass s_XPdfID = 0;
static jmethodID s_XPdfConstructorMethodID=0;
static jmethodID s_XPdfSumMethodID=0;
jobject m_XPdfObject;

JNIEXPORT jint JNI_OnLoad(JavaVM* vm, void*)
{
    JNIEnv* env;

    if (vm->GetEnv(reinterpret_cast<void**>(&env), JNI_VERSION_1_6) != JNI_OK) {
        qCritical()<<"Can't get the enviroument";
        return -1;
    }

    s_javaVM = vm;
    jclass clazz=env->FindClass("PdfCore/Pdf");
    if (!clazz)
    {
        qCritical()<<"Can't find Pdf class";
        return -1;
    }
    return JNI_VERSION_1_6;
}
```

jni.h file undefine following

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
 * VM initialization functions.
 *
 * Note these are the only symbols exported for JNI by the VM.
 */
#if 0  /* In practice, these are not exported by the NDK so don't declare them */
jint JNI_GetDefaultJavaVMInitArgs(void*);
jint JNI_CreateJavaVM(JavaVM**, JNIEnv**, void*);
jint JNI_GetCreatedJavaVMs(JavaVM**, jsize, jsize*);
#endif
```

Comment: Is the jar on your runtime classpath?

Comment: @Jorn i am new to JNI, how can i add my jar file to classpath.

Comment: When running the program, pass the classpath to the vm: `$> java -cp <classpath> <main class>`. See more info here: [Setting the class path](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html)

Comment: @JornVernee Inside qt how can i do it? JNI_OnLoad is called internally.

Comment: You could try using `-Djava.class.path=<classpath>`. But how are you running your application?

Comment: @JornVernee Could u see the updates. i am making andriod app using QT,thers is no option to set -Djava.class.path=<‌​classpath>. i mean VMInitArgs

Comment: Even in android there should be a way to set the classpath. I don't know the specifics for android though...

Comment: i have add my jar file andriod/libs folder it's started working. Thanks Jorn.